# Table widths/div not correct

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I am using a Javascript method to sync the column widths of two tables. The code for the HTML, CSS, and Javascript are below. The table columns sync fine when the divs are the size of or larger than the tables, but when there is overflow (currently hidden as I'll be adding scrolling later) the table columns do not align. I know that the table widths and column widths are setting fine (I use a logger to check the style.width of each), but they are displaying misaligned by around 12 px.

I've really been baffled by this for a while and could really use the help. Ideas?

CSS

```
 /*
APTEIT.css
Author: Steven T. Norris     Created: 2/28/2012
Updated By:                  Last Updated:
Copyright 2012

CSS stylesheet for default page of APTEIT
*/

/*Utilities Styles*/
.debug
{
    display:block;
}
.LOG_INFO
{
    color:blue;
}

.tbl
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
.tbl tr td
{
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:black;
    border-style:solid;
}

#headersDiv
{
    max-width:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#dataDiv
{
    max-width:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#headers
{
    table-layout:auto;
}
#data
{
    table-layout:auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<%@language = "C#" inherits="APTEIT.Default"%>
<!--
Default.aspx
Author: Steven T. Norris    Created: 2/28/2012
Last Updated:   Updated By: 
Default page of APTEIT
-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/APTEIT.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Utilities/Javascript/Utilities.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Utilities/Javascript/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    HtmlLoggerControlInstance.getInstance().setLevel("debug",HtmlLogger.ALL);
    syncColumnWidths("headers",null,"data",null);
});
</script>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>APTEIT</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--#include file="Utilities/Debug.aspx"-->
        <img src="Images/logo.png" />
        <div id="headersDiv">
            <table class="tbl" id="headers">
                <tr>
                    <td>head1</td>
                    <td>head2reallyreallylong</td>
                    <td>hd3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="dataDiv" onscroll="syncScrolling('dataDiv','headersDiv');">
            <table class="tbl" id="data">
            <tr>
                <td>alsdja;lksdjaljkdf</td>
                <td>kdki</td>
                <td>k39</td>
                <td>lsjdl</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>alsdja;lksdjaljkdf</td>
                <td>kdki</td>
                <td>k39</td>
                <td>lsjdl</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>alsdja;lksdjaljkdasdfaf</td>
                <td>kdki</td>
                <td>k39</td>
                <td>lsjdl</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>alsdja;lksdjaljkdf</td>
                <td>kdki</td>
                <td>k39</td>
                <td>lsjdl</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>alsdja;lksdjaljkdfs</td>
                <td>kdki</td>
                <td>k39</td>
                <td>lsjdl</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>alsdf</td>
                <td>kdki</td>
                <td>k39</td>
                <td>lsjdl</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
/*
Utilities.js
Author: Steven T. Norris     Created: 3/2/2012
Updated By:                  Last Updated:
Copyright 2012

Utility functions
Logs to debug window if using Debug.aspx or a logger named 'debug' with the HtmlLoggerControlInstance
*/

/*
Syncs column sizes between two tables. 

@param string table1 : First table to sync
@param int table1HeadRow : Row to use as column width sync for table1 (if null, uses first row)
@param string table2 : Second table to sync
@param int table2HeadRow : Row to use as column width sync for table2 (if null, uses first row)
*/
function syncColumnWidths(table1, table1HeadRow, table2, table2HeadRow) {
    var tableTotal = 0
    UtilLogger.log(HtmlLogger.INFO,"-Syncing Column Widths-")
    if((typeof table1 == "string" ||table1.constructor == String) && (typeof table2 == "string" ||table2.constructor == String)
        && (typeof table1HeadRow == "number" || table1HeadRow == null) && (typeof table2HeadRow == "number" || table1HeadRow == null)){
        tableOne = document.getElementById(table1);
        tableTwo = document.getElementById(table2);

        //Set row to check and get row
        if(table1HeadRow == null){
            t1Start = 0;
        }
        else{
            t1Start = table1HeadRow;
        }
        if(table2HeadRow == null){
            t2Start = 0;
        }
        else{
            t2Start = table2HeadRow;
        }
        t1Row = tableOne.rows[t1Start];
        t2Row = tableTwo.rows[t2Start];

        //Get end number
        if(t1Row.cells.length < t2Row.cells.length){
            tEnd = t1Row.cells.length;
        }
        else{
            tEnd = t2Row.cells.length;
        }

        //Sync widths
        for(i = 0; i < tEnd; i++){
            UtilLogger.log(HtmlLogger.CONFIG,"syncColumnWidths:t1 width:"+t1Row.cells[i].offsetWidth+"   t2 width:"+t2Row.cells[i].offsetWidth);
            if(t1Row.cells[i].offsetWidth > t2Row.cells[i].offsetWidth){
                t2Row.cells[i].style.width = t1Row.cells[i].offsetWidth+"px";
                t1Row.cells[i].style.width = t1Row.cells[i].offsetWidth+"px";
                UtilLogger.log(HtmlLogger.FINE,"syncColumnWidths:setting t2 width to t1");
                UtilLogger.log(HtmlLogger.FINER, "syncColumnwidths:t1 style width:" + t1Row.cells[i].style.width + "    t2 style width:" + t2Row.cells[i].style.width);
                tableTotal = tableTotal + t1Row.cells[i].offsetWidth
            }
            else{
                t1Row.cells[i].style.width = t2Row.cells[i].offsetWidth+"px";
                t2Row.cells[i].style.width = t2Row.cells[i].offsetWidth+"px";
                UtilLogger.log(HtmlLogger.FINE,"syncColumnWidths:setting t1 width to t2");
                UtilLogger.log(HtmlLogger.FINER,"syncColumnwidths:t1 style width:"+t1Row.cells[i].style.width+"    t2 style width:"+t2Row.cells[i].style.width);
                tableTotal = tableTotal + t2Row.cells[i].offsetWidth
            }
        }
        UtilLogger.log(HtmlLogger.FINE, "setting main table width to " + tableTotal);
        tableOne.style.width = tableTotal + "px"
        tableTwo.style.width = tableTotal + "px"
        UtilLogger.log(HtmlLogger.FINER, "tableOne width: " + tableOne.style.width);
        UtilLogger.log(HtmlLogger.FINER, "tableTwo width: " + tableTwo.style.width);

    }
    else{
        alert("syncColumnWidths takes parameters (string, int|null, string, int|null)");
    }
    UtilLogger.log(HtmlLogger.INFO,"-Syncing Column Widths Complete-");
}

/*
Syncs scrolling of two divs. Meant to be part of onscroll event for primary div 

@param string div1 : primary div. normally the div who's onclick event houses this method
@param string div2 : secondary div
*/
function syncScrolling(div1,div2){
    if((typeof div1 == "string" || div1.constructor == String) && (typeof div2 == "string" || div2.cosntructor == String)){
        $("#"+div2).scrollLeft($("#"+div1).scrollLeft());
    }
    else{
        alert("syncScrolling takes parameters (string, string)");
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Border and Padding width javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9842018/border-and-padding-width-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double posted and answered in new thread

see below link

[Border and Padding width javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9842018/border-and-padding-width-javascript)